# Is my PowerShell script inefficient?

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script to delete temporary files/folders older than 90 days on remote servers. The server.txt file is loaded with Get-Content, and I use 'net use' to map to the IPC$ share. I'm worried that I'm not using Best Practices to delete the old temp files. Here is the meat of my script:

```
net use \\$server\IPC$ /user:$Authname $pw /persistent:yes
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$($server)\C$\Temp" -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastAccessTime -lt $cutoffdate} | Remove-Item -Recurse
(Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$($server)\C$\Temp" -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | Where-Object {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0} | Remove-Item -Recurse
net use \\$Server\IPC$ /delete
```

The first gci deletes old files, the second deletes empty folders.

The reason I'm concerned is that in my initial tests, it's taking about a half hour to delete approximately 4 gb off of one server. And I work in a big shop; my script needs to be run against about 10,000 servers. At that rate my script won't be done for more than six months, and I was hoping to run it on a quarterly basis.

Am I doing something the hard way?

Comment: If at all possible I would run the script in a remote session on each server. Then you could run it as jobs for each server, and run them all at the same time.

Comment: If you update to ps 4 you can use the -file and -container switches of GCI which filter much much faster than piping the objects to where, even with the remaining where being necessary. Also on the first GCI I don't believe -recurse would be necessary for remove-item.

Comment: Is this pretty much exactly what the powershell job abstraction exists for?

Answer (score 2):

1. get a list of your servers
2. cycle through the list and use invoke-command -computername
3. your command will be executed on the remote server rather than pulling all the data across the network which is very slow

Comment: I agree, from experience, all those extra calls across the network are almost certainly your bottleneck.

Comment: also,  invoke-command can accept multiple computer names and will parallelize the task for you